# How to test for object passed as ...rest argument to a function

Tags: javascript, rest-parameters

I am practicing using `...rest` operator to pass arguments to functions. I have run into an issue that I'm unable to resolve for when passing an object to the function.

Here is the function:

```
function sum(...args){
  if (args.length === 1 && Array.isArray(args[0])) {
    args = args[0];
  }
  return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}

console.log(sum([5,4,3,2,1])); // Returns 15
console.log(sum(5,4,3,2,1)); // Returns 15
console.log(sum({a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1})); // Returns {a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1}
```

I'm stuck at how to test for and handle the last use case.

Comment: This will work for both arrays and objects: `if (args[0] && typeof args[0] === "object") { args = Object.values(args[0]); }`

Comment: Thats true for both[] (first example) and {} (last example). My question is how to differentiate between those two as they are both objects but the latter cannot be properly reduced without the conversion.

Comment: You can use `args[0] && Object.prototype.toString.call(args[0]) === '[object Object]'` if you want to be really explicit.

Comment: 1/2 ...One just does not do that. The function's arguments signature and its usage indicates an array of arguments and not a single argument which then only might be an object type. **There is no reason for introducing fuzziness to the function's arguments.**  As for the 3rd use case one would just pass the object's values to the function like this ...`sum(...Object.values({a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1}))`... and not the other way around, guessing / detecting the arguments and trying to adapt to varying argument signatures. And the 1st use case has to be ...`sum(...[5,4,3,2,1])`... with the function...

Comment: 2/2 ... simplifying to `function sum(...args){ return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b); }`

Comment: @PeterSeliger the drawback of the spread syntax it's much slower and can overflow the stack, so passing an array reference is still valid, though passing an object is overkill. Array::concat works this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your object to an array with `Object.values`, passing an object instead of an array is an overkill:

```js
function sum(...args){
  if (args.length === 1 && Array.isArray(args[0])) {
    args = args[0];
  }
  return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}

console.log(sum([5,4,3,2,1])); // Returns 15
console.log(sum(5,4,3,2,1)); // Returns 15
console.log(sum(Object.values({a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1}))) //
```

Also you could possibly improve your function with `Array::flat()`.
That way it will behave the same as `Array::concat()`. I like that.

```js
function sum(...args){
  return args.flat().reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}

console.log(sum([5,4,3,2,1])); // Returns 15
console.log(sum(5,4,3,2,1)); // Returns 15
console.log(sum(Object.values({a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1}))) // Returns 15
console.log(sum(
  [5,4,3,2,1],
  5,4,3,2,1,
  Object.values({a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1})
)); // Returns 45
```

I wouldn't convert an object to an array automatically inside `sum` but if you need:

```js
function sum(...args){
  return args
    .map(arg => typeof arg === 'object' && !Array.isArray(arg) ? Object.values(arg) : arg)
    .flat()
    .reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}

console.log(sum([5,4,3,2,1])); // Returns 15
console.log(sum(5,4,3,2,1)); // Returns 15
console.log(sum({a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1})) // Returns 15
console.log(sum(
  [5,4,3,2,1],
  5,4,3,2,1,
  {a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1}
)); // Returns 45
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Object.values` for both cases (object and array):

```js
function sum(...args){
  if (args.length === 1 && args[0] && typeof args[0] === 'object') {
    args = Object.values(args[0]);
  }
  return args.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}

console.log(sum([5,4,3,2,1]));
console.log(sum(5,4,3,2,1));
console.log(sum({a:5,b:4,c:3,d:2,e:1}));
```

Comment: If it already is an array however, you should not use `Object.values` unnecessarily